# How do I know where a specific global variable is from in Swift?

Tags: swift, variables

As in Java, if the variable is in different file, we have to such as below:
Ex: difinition.java :

```
public final static Stirng WEB_URL = "https://www.google.com"
```

> Ex: main.java: difinition.WEB_URL ...

So I could easily know where is the variable from. But in Swift when you leave the variable in different files, you just need to call WEB_URL without "difinition.", how can I do?

Because I tried struct and class, both of them gonna create a new instance not the original one.

Comment: Are you looking for static variable? `struct MyConstants{ static let webURLString = "https://google.com" }` and in use `let str = MyConstants.webURLString`?

Comment: @Larme how about non-static variable? like the value will be change but all the controller has the chance to use it

Comment: `static` in Swift, means "Class/Struct variable, not an instance one". It's the `let`/`var` that will defined the mutability. So if the value might change, use `static var` instead of `static let`.

Comment: Understanding of the difference between instance properties and static properties is the key.

Comment: Got it, thanks both of you :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a global variable that you can access anywhere in project then you can create a general class and create a static variable like:

```
Myclass {

    static let str_Url = "link"
}
```

Here you can access directly varaible using class name or

```
Myclass {

  static let sharedInstance = Myclass()
  
  func myFunc() {

  }
}
```

now you can access this calss variable and use its variable any where